# What does "a voice carries" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

> It is as far from my house as a man's voice carries.

What does the "man's voice carries" part mean?

Answer (score 1):

When we say "a voice carries", we mean the distance the voice (or sound in general) can be heard from. See definition 4 of the second listing [here](http://thefreedictionary.com/carry).